# jquery ui autocomplete multiple remote not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

So I can search the database and return the values I want but when I attempt to add more than one value to the input field, the search request returns no results.

my javascript:

```
$(function() {
function split( val ) {
    return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}   
function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#tags" )
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
    $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})

.autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "search.php",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { value: item.tag };
                }))

            }
        })
    },

    search: function() {
        // custom minLength
        var term = extractLast( this.value );
        if ( term.length < 2 ) {
            return false;
        }
    },

    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },

    select: function( event, ui  ) {
        var terms = split( this.value );
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push( "" );
        this.value = terms.join( ", " );
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

and my returned json looks like this:

```
[{"tag":"tag1"},{"tag":"tag2"}]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: nevermind, I added `data: { term: extractLast( request.term ) }` to `$.jax` which fixed the problem.

Comment: $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: your data comes here
    });